# How to integrate essl identix device?

Tags: integration

I am trying to get the data from "essl identix" biometric device. But can't found any documentation for this. I am expecting the SDK/API in Python/Java/PHP/.NET

Answer (score 0):

Identix devices are ZkTeco versions only. You can use the SDK downloaded from https://www.zkteco.com/en/download_catgory.html. SDK is supported for TCP/IP Communication and works only on Windows. If you need http communication, for language/platform independent, refer http://camsunit.com/application/zk-teco-essl-api-integration.html

Comment: [https://www.zkteco.com/en/download_catgory.html](https://www.zkteco.com/en/download_catgory.html) link does not work now, please update your answer

Comment: it also requires a whopping 36000$ api engine to be installed, which is a turn off for most sane people